# PowerApps button is missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I am new to PowerApps and not sure why I do not see the PowerApps button on the action menu.

Am I missing something?

[image]

FYI, Preview feature is enabled for my test tenant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerApps are not available to customize libraries, only lists. Someone commented about this on a [blog post](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-form-launch/), and a microsoft rep said that adding this capability was on their backlog. Unfortunately, that was a year ago.